Font shape `T1/lato-TLF/b/sc' undefined, Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted
When I am compiling an overleaf document with \documentclass[num-refs]{wiley-article}, and the packages \WarningFilter{latex}{Text page 8 contains only floats}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xspace} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

encountered this warning seems a crucial error to rectify.

You should provide an example, but the warning means the font you have chosen (which is not selected by the code shown) does not have small caps.
